# Has anyone ever won a field medal for inventing stochastic calculus?

Tags: soft-question, math-history, stochastic-calculus

I somehow wondered today why was Ito never awarded a Fields medal for inventing Ito calculus?

I also wonder has anyone ever been awarded a Fields medal for building the foundation of stochastic calculus? or has anyone won a Fields medal for research on stochastic calculus?

EDIT: 
If people actually read the answer as given, I think it is rather factual. Also, I find it totally ridiculous that people have voted to close AFTER I have accepted an answer.

Comment: I guess anyone can ask the same question about any significant progress in any area of maths...

Comment: Another point is that they only give Fields medals to people under 40.

Comment: Since exactly one person invented the stochastic calculus, you could make the questio more precise!

Comment: Unfortunately there's a widespread misbelief that the Fields medals are the equivalent to a Nobel Prize in mathematics. I think this is completely wrong. One of the conditions to win the FM, which imo is ridiculous **if** one wants to compare it with a Nobel, is that the mathematician must be under 40 years old. For this condition, people like A. Wiles, who proved (together with R. Taylor) Fermat's Last Theorem, wasn't awarded the medal. I'm not sure how this prize, as important and meaningful as it may be, got to be compared to the Nobels...perhaps it was the first one in maths or something.

Comment: Why wasn't he awarded an Abel prize or Gauss prize?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Gauss prize in 2006.

Comment: @fretty yes, but I am not going to do that, as algebraic geometry and many other things people were rewarded Fields Medal for are not my fields of interest...

Comment: You miss my point...the question is too opinionated and so has no answer other than "He just didn't". I could ask the question "How come so and so didn't get a Fields medal for that lovely thing I like that he/she invented back in the 60's" and you would be forced to either say "Well I am not interested in that so I don't see why he/she should have got one" or "He/she just didn't".

Comment: @fretty "the question (...) has no answer other than "He just didn't"." I see your point and I think your point is wrong. I read three factual reasons in the first paragraph of my answer and a fourth, semi-factual, one in the second paragraph.

Comment: So you say he was not seen as "an early genius" at the time. Surely this is opinionated and is just a reformulation of "He just didn't, maybe because...".

Comment: @fretty dude, I think you have nothing to gain by arguing against a top probability professor on a subject you know nothing about. even more so as you had nothing constructive to add to this discussion. I believe I asked a reasonable question about mathematical history. History is, after all, full of opinions, backed by facts and reasons. That is, facts, not in the sense of theorems and lemmas. You can, of course, answer 'why did Napoleon not win the battle of Waterloo' with the same 'he just did not', but I think this is a very negative approach to this type of questions.

Comment: I will cease to comment if that is how you feel...but does it really matter who I am arguing with? This is not a question about probability! The "fact" remains, it is still an opinionated question with at best a "historically factual" answer (hence why at least 4 people have put the question on hold). What do you gain by knowing an answer apart from "well he didn't (and this is probably why) but I think he should have"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> why was Ito never awarded a <strike>field</strike> Fields medal for inventing Ito calculus?

A part of the explanation is that, due to WWII, only [the three first ICMs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fields_Medal) (in 1936, 1950 and 1954) were held before 1955, when Itô (born in 1915) reached the age limit of 40. Plus, Itô was not seen as an early genius at the time, his contributions being somewhat more slowly recognized than others'. Plus, the fact that at the time probability theory was regarded as "true" mathematics mainly in the USSR, also in Japan and in some circles in France, much less so in the US and in other countries.

And really, the medalists in 1936, 1950 and 1954 (to limit oneself to the ICMs held before Itô reached 40) are considered as mathematical giants still today, no? (With the exception of Douglas, perhaps, who seems to be more rarely mentioned or remembered than the others, nowadays.)

> has anyone ever been awarded a <strike>field</strike> Fields medal for building the foundation of stochastic calculus?

No. This would have been Itô.

> has anyone won a <strike>field</strike> Fields medal for research on stochastic calculus?

No.

Note that probability theory in the wide sense is definitely on the radar of the Fields committee these days, with medals awarded to Werner in 2006 and to Smirnov in 2010 (but, to stay focused on your question, neither of these two is mainly concerned with stochastic calculus).

Comment: Thank you. When I asked this question, I thought you'd probably be the best person to answer it...

Comment: Your answer now needs an update because of Martin Hairer. :)

Comment: Indeed... :-) $ $

Answer (score 1):

The Fields medal was first awarded in $1936$, and is awarded every four years, each time to at most four people, so there haven't been that many Fields medallists. A complete list including an indication of their area of primary research is given in a table [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fields_Medal#Fields_medalists). Even though no person has anything involving "stochastic" listed in their primary research entry, there might be someone whose contributions included stochastic calculus.

Comment: Replaced the link by one accessible to everyone.

Comment: "there might be someone whose contributions included stochastic calculus" None as a motivation for the medal.

Comment: @Did: Was the last link not accesible by everyone? I did not need to login and I am unaware of any reason I would have access to it, but others wouldn't. I chose that link as opposed to the Wikipedia one as it lists the area of primary research.

Comment: I tried it and was rebuffed.